# Compare Strings and Char Position with Python and Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare some plate text with my DataFrame (my xlsx file) using Pandas. I've tried already to use image treatment and other precision improvement techniques, although there still some errors like switching I's with 1's or even l's.

What I'm trying to do is a similarity tester, like:

"If 6 of 7 letters are the same in the registered plate DataFrame, approve something."

```
[All the imported dependencies, like pandas, numpy, PyTesseract and etc.]

pos = 0 # Iloc pos in DataFrame
i = 0 # Char Position 
ok_count = 0 # Counter

xlsx_path = "C\My Computer\Downloads\Python\Project.xlsx"
registered_plates = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)

for plateR.iloc(pos) in registered_plates:

      # if plate in dataframe == plate collected
      if plateR[i] == plateC[i]
         i += 1
         ok_count += 1

         # If count less than 6, iloc +1
         if ok_count < 6:
             pos += 1
             i = 0
             ok_count = 0

         break

# The % formula
formula = (ok_count/((len(plateR.iloc(pos))*100)

value = f'{formula:5.2f}'
f_value = float(value)

# Normally, if 6 of 7, the value will become 85.28%
if f_value >= 80.00:
   print("Minimum Value Acquired.", \n, "Sending Access Signal.")

# Send the similar plate in DataFrame
   print("DataFrame Similar Plate: ", placasR.iloc(pos))

   publish.single(...)

else:
   print("Minimum Value Not Reached.", \n, "Try to read again.")

   publish.single(...0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached an answer, hopefully this works most of the time. Use with wisdom.

```
    pos = 0 # Plate or Text Position on DataFrame
    digitpos = 0 # The digit position
    counter = 0 # Same digit counter

    plateC = plate_text # CollectedPlate/Text = Text in Code
        
    while digitpos < 7: # While the digit position stay lower than 7
            
        plateR = df.iloc[pos, 0]  # RegisteredPlate or Text on DataFrame
        lenghtDF = len(df["Column"].index)

        if len(plateR) == len(plateC): # If they have the same lenght, runs the code, this works specifically for PlateRecog Systems
            
                
        else: 
            break # or main() to run the code again
            
        if plateR[digitpos] == plateC[digitpos]: #if they have the same digit in this position
            digitpos += 1; counter += 1 +1 # Then go to the next digit and approve
                
        else: 
            digitpos += 1 # Only go to the next
            
        if (digitpos == 7) and (counter < 6): # Digit 7 and low approvals? Go to the next plate
            pos += 1; counter = 0; digitpos = 0 
            
        if (digitpos == 7) and (counter >= 6): # Break the loop and approve
            break 

        if pos > lenghtDF: # If the actual position on dataFrame is equal as the last position, then break.
             break
```